# Can i implement brightness feature like apple wallet app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, wallet

Apple wallet set full brightness when app is on foreground. when app goes in background or terminate it will reset as normal brightness.

I want to implement same feature with my app.

I try with `[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0];` 
Brightness changes made by an app remain in effect until the device is locked.

I want to set full brightness if my app is in foreground mode else brightness will reset to previous level of brightness.

Comment: I don't see a problem that you have. Could you describe your problem in more detail?

Comment: check i update question and you can check in wallet app also. it already have this feature.

Comment: I think I understand, you want the brightness to reset when you close your app, which is not the current behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

**ALL THIS FINALLY DOESN'T WORK, SEE EDIT**

If what you do is setting high brightness when opening your app, then restore previous brightness when existing, here's what you can do in `AppDelegate` :

Add a `CGFloat previousBrightness`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    previousBrightness = [[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness];

    [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0];

    return YES;
}
```

And

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:previousBrightness];
}
```

**Edit :**

After some research, I found that **there's actually a bug in iOS that prevent you to change brightness after exiting an app**. The bug has been reported since iOS 4 and doesn't seem to be solved as I tried on iOS 8 and it still doesn't work...

Please see [this thread on Apple Dev Forum](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/139813?start=0&tstart=0) for further informations about the bug.

The only thing you can do is setting full brightness for the very single step you need it, and reset just when user doesn't need anymore. For example in many apps, we have full brightness when viewing QR-Code, then it restore to previous brightness when clicking on the cross 'X' to exit.

You'll maybe have to rethink your app in some ways but you'll not have the ability to restore brightness after user click on Home button.

Comment: Was just writing this answer :)

Comment: I already try this before post Question. It was not work when app goes in background. yes it works when app terminate.

Comment: After trying I found with surprise that this doesn't work, please see my edit.

Comment: @AnthoninC. I also spend some hours but not get proper solution. And  did you check wallet app? it works perfect which i want. and even when wallet app set full brightness that time system brightness not changed you can check in control-center when wallet app is in foreground. where `setBrightness` change system brightness.

Comment: @Shreyank Maybe there's an (undocumented) method that allows to change brightness inside an app only. But it's probably restricted to Apple apps...